# ヘルプ・センターの改善

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

まず、[ヘルプ・センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)をご覧ください。

48件の記事があります。英語の記事も多いです。

次に、[Stack Overflow開始当初のヘルプ](http://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/https://stackoverflow.com/faq)をご覧ください。

簡単で短いです。

英語のStack Overflowは今年6歳になります。そろそろ小学校一年生（成長は早いものですね・・・）。Stack Overflowが徐々に成長するにつれ、コミュニティが問題に直面してはそれを解決する指針を追加してきた結果が、今のヘルプ・センターです。

スタック・オーバーフロー（日本語版）はStack Overflow（英語版）とは違います。目的は同じですが、コミュニティは一緒ではありません。そのため、ルールを大量に翻訳するより、簡単なヘルプをまず作成したいと思っています。とりあえず5年前の英語版のヘルプをベースにした最小限のヘルプを書きました。直接そちらにコメントしたり、編集して改善してもらってもいいですし、他の形・言葉・アイデアがあれば、新しい回答として投稿していただいても大丈夫です。

Comment: 現在のヘルプセンターは、公開はしないものですか? 不自然な箇所の指摘を投稿しようかどうか迷っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結果的に、従来のヘルプセンターを残しながら、メインページにワンページの説明を追加しました（文言は以下）。ヘルプセンターの記事へのリンクが多いため、残さないといけませんが、初心者向けにわかりやすくまとめた説明を足せば理解しやすいと考えました。

> ### よくある質問
>
> #### どんな質問を聞けば良いですか？
>
> プログラミングに関する質問はもちろん何でも大歓迎です！ただし以下のことに気をつけてください。
>
> - 内容が具体的で詳細であること
> - 質問内容をわかりやすく説明すること
> - 誰か一人でも世の中の他のプログラマーに役に立つような内容であること
>
> この3点を満たしてさえいれば、あなたが初心者でもスーパークリエイターでも関係なく歓迎します。
>
> それから、聞きたい質問がすでに投稿されているか、まずは検索してみてください。見当たらなければ、遠慮なく質問を投稿してください。
> 後から重複していると分かってもノープロブレム。これから先、同じ内容を検索した人が回答にたどりつく助けになります。
>
> 自分の質問に対して、自分で回答しても大丈夫です。
>
> #### 避けた方がよい質問はありますか？
>
> 主観的であったり、炎上を招く内容であったり、長々とした議論が必要になるような質問は避けてください。ここは明快な答えが出せるような質問のための場所です！
>
> サイト自体についての質問があれば、[スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)でお聞きください。
>
> #### 礼儀を忘れずに
>
> みんな何かしら学ぶためにこの場にアクセスしています。お互いに尊敬しあい良いサイトを作り上げて行きましょう。自分より知識の少ない人には寛容に、スマイルを忘れずに。
>
> #### ごまかさない
>
> このサイトの第一のモットーは、正直であれ、です。正しくない情報を見つけたら、マイナス投票してください。
> そしてコメント欄でどこが間違っているかを具体的に説明してあげてください！  他の人の投稿を編集することもできます －
> サイトのコンテンツを編集を通して改善していきましょう！
>
> #### ユーザー登録やログインは必要ですか？
>
> 一切必要ありません。 質問も回答も匿名で投稿することができます。
> ユーザー登録して初めてアクセスできる機能も一部あります。ユーザー登録したくなったら、FacebookやGoogleなどのOpenID機能を使ってとても簡単にすませることができます。
>
> #### 「信用度」とは何ですか？
>
> まず、質問と回答を投稿するだけであれば「信用度」は一切気にする必要はありません。
>
> スタック・オーバーフローはユーザーのみなさんが運営するコミュニティです。運営に関わる機能にアクセスするために「信用度」というポイントが必要になります。
> このポイントはコミュニティからどの程度あなたが信用されているかを示すおおまかな数値です。「信用度」は、おいそれと手に入るものではありません。あなたが投稿したコンテンツを他のユーザーから評価してもらうことを通して獲得できる仕組みになっています。
>
> 例えば、よい質問や回答を投稿したら、他のユーザーからプラス票がつきます。サイトに無関係な質問や、正しくない回答を投稿するとマイナス票がつきます。
> プラス票がつくと信用度が増え（質問：5点、回答：10点）、マイナス票なら2点減ります。
>
> 信用度は投票により次のように変化します：
>
> - +5　自分の質問にプラス票がつく
> - +10　自分の回答にプラス票がつく
> - +15　自分の回答が質問者によって選ばれる
> - +2　回答を選んで自分の質問を解決済みにする
> - -2　自分の質問にマイナス票がつく
> - -2　自分の回答にマイナス票がつく
> - -0　質問にマイナス投票する
> - -1　回答にマイナス投票する
>
> 一日あたり獲得できる信用度は最大200点までです。
> 信用度がたまると質問や回答の投稿以外にもいろいろなことができる[権限が徐々に解放されていきます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)。
>
> 信用度を通じて権限を獲得していくと、最終的にはできることが公式のモデレーターとほとんど変わらなくなってきます。モデレーターがスタック・オーバーフローの責任者なのではありません。スタック・オーバーフローはあくまでもユーザーのコミュニティーなのです。
>
> #### なぜ他の人が私の投稿を編集できるのですか？
>
> ウィキペディアと同じようにスタック・オーバーフローは共同作業でコンテンツを改善していく仕組みを取り入れています。
> 自分の質問や回答を編集されると不愉快な気分になる人には、残念ながらこのサイトは合わないかもしれません。
>
> #### あとそれから...
>
> ここまででカバーできていない質問があれば、[スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)で「サポート」のタグを付けてお聞きください。

Comment: 現在ワンページのヘルプはできないらしいですので、解決方法は検討中です。

Comment: それではヘルプセンターの記事は全部残すのですね? であれば不自然な箇所を投稿するようにします

Comment: @ento とりあえずそうです。あっちこっちからリンクがあるため、残さないと大変らしいです。残りの記事は優先度をつけて改善できるし、他のアイデアがあれば大歓迎です！

Comment: 盲目的にルールとして受け入れてほしくない、を表現するために、背景に「ベータ」という透かしを入れるとか ([イメージ](https://www.google.com/search?q=draft+watermark&espv=2&biw=1006&bih=517&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=g3ZlVJW2Aue2mQWu74G4Dg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ))

Comment: @ento このワンページヘルプにだけですか？サイト全体ですか？

Comment: ヘルプセンターの記事全部に、と思ってました。

Comment: ワンページヘルプで言い回しが気になるところなどを編集しました。問題なければ適用をおねがいします

Comment: モデレーターパワーで適用しました。他のアイデアとして、必要ないと考えるヘルプページは一旦まっさらな白紙にしてしまうとか