# 英語が残っている箇所: 「プライベートベータでの質問方法」ページの「関連サイト」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

スクショ:

[image: 最初の質問の前に]

「Stack Exchangeの哲学」的なブログ記事へのリンクです。英語SOと日本語SOは違うコミュニティとはいえ、数年かけて培ったノウハウは引き継いだ方がよいのじゃないかと思います。リンクされている記事については、メタにfaq記事として要約を載せておくのはどうでしょうか。

関連:

[ヘルプ・センターの改善](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97-%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E6%94%B9%E5%96%84)

Comment: 上記のアドバイスをオフにできるかを検討しています。プライベートベータでは誘っている人全員はネットワーク利用者のため、この注意は不要かもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

> 英語SOと日本語SOは違うコミュニティとはいえ、数年かけて培ったノウハウは引き継いだ方がよいのじゃないかと思います。

もちろん、必要に応じてその哲学を共有しましょう。しかし、コミュニティが話し合った上で適切な記事を当コミュニティ向けに作成したらどうですか？

当社の心配は最初からこの記事をすべて翻訳するとコミュニティがそれはルールと思ってしまい、新しいユーザー（SO英語に参加したことがないユーザー）に不親切の可能性もあります。

[はしごと猿の話](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-condu)は聞いたことがありますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「なぜ」を理解しないといけません。

> リンクされている記事については、メタにfaq記事として要約を載せておくのはどうでしょうか。

これは可能です。SOポルトガル語版ではSO哲学のブログ記事をメタで翻訳しました：[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)等

Comment: どこかで読みました、はしごと猿の話。そして「必要に応じてその哲学を共有」に同意です。ただ、Area 51発足サイトでGood subjective, bad subjectiveなどの記事を簡単に参照できるようにしているならば、日本語SOでも同じ環境を整えていいのではないかとも思います。 (それとも日本の文化としてルールに感化されやすい？) とはいえそれもコストがかかるし時期尚早な最適化かもしれないので、議論ができる枠組み (SEプラットフォーム) と、SO哲学を知っているユーザーとモデレーターがある程度いればいいのかなとも思います。

Comment: 「ルールと思ってしま」わないための簡便な手法として、サイトのバージョンを「アルファ」としてスタートするのもありかと思います。いつ「ベータ」にするかが問題ですが。

Comment: @ento, 現在は「アルファ」ですが、SEでは「アルファ」を「プライベートベータ」と読んでいます。

Comment: この記事を読むと、主観的質問もルール化する以前に利用者自身が学ぶ必要があったのではないかと思います。