# 「弊社」「...してください」などコミュニティが前面に出ていない表現は言い換えた方がよい?

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

この質問の意図としては、「弊社」「...してください」は基本的に望ましくない、という考え方の是非を皆さんにお聞きしたいです。具体的に各表現をどう言い換えるかはこの質問の範囲外とします。

### 「弊社」

英語版のSEネットワークサイトを使っていて、会社が運営しているということを今まであまり意識したことがありません。同好者による同好者のためのコミュニティ、というイメージが強いです。それに比べ、今の日本語版では「弊社」「当社」という言いかたが目につきます。

- [`弊社のモデル`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)
- `当社に応募` (サイトフッター)

→ 「コミュニティ」を主語に持ってくる、「弊社」に言及せずに済ませるなど

### 「してください」

[運用ルールはコミュニティが決める](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/32/30) という方針と相反する効果がありそうです。

- `「ありがとうございます」などのコメントは避けてください。` ("コメントを追加"のツールチップ)
- `どうしても必要な場合以外、行わないでください。` (他人の投稿を編集する時のトップバナー)

→ 不自然でない限り「しましょう」「お願いします」と言い換える

どうでしょうか。

Comment: 日本人じゃないため、丁寧レベル・日本語の雰囲気の判断が上手くできません。現在ネイティブの校正者と話しています。校正者に英語を読ませて、その雰囲気をすべての日本語のページに適用することを頼もうと計画はしています。もちろんここでスタイルのヒントがあれば、それを渡すとともに頼みますので、提案よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 7):

> 同好者による同好者のためのコミュニティ、というイメージが強いです。それに比べ、今の日本語版では「弊社」「当社」という言いかたが目につきます。

私も「弊社」という言い回しには、強い違和感をうけました。指摘通り、コミュニティ中心であることを意識した訳が望ましいと思います。

> 「してください」
> 運用ルールはコミュニティが決める という方針と相反する効果がありそうです。

「してください」については丁寧語の語尾という印象のみであり、個人的にはそこまで気になりませんでした。ただし、「しましょう」「お願いします」への言い換えを否定するものではありません。

---

@2020/07/01
以下の通りサイトに反映されていることを確認いたしました。
弊社のモデル -> 私たちのモデル
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/4739

[image: We, the users of SOja..]

「弊社」が含まれるストリングは、全て別の言葉に置き換えられました。
https://ja.traducir.win/filters?translationRegex=(%3Fi)%E5%BC%8A%E7%A4%BE

Comment: @aki 回答に事実を追記頂いたようですが、これは私の意見とは区別されるべきものです。混乱を避けるためコミュニティWiki化しました。

Comment: Wiki化どうもありがとうございます。（別の回答として書くべきでした‍♀️。。失礼いたしました！）