# 英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

例えば:

[「おすすめを教えてください」系の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/158810#158810)

- [Markdown に含まれるコードをシンタックスハイライトするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/165/)
- [EmacsをJava用IDEとして使い倒せるパッケージはありますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73/)

[リンクだけの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

- [phpで文字列がメールアドレスか判定するには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/159/30)

まずはメタで話し合うのがよいでしょうか。

---

**補足:**

Stack Exchangeは独自の哲学をもったQ&Aサイトプラットフォームです。
私がこれまでSEのネットワークサイトに参加してきて感じるその哲学は、「質問する人にも回答する人にも、あとから読む人にも役立つサイトであるべし」というものです。
「あとから読む人」もユーザーとして捉えているので、リンクだけの回答は不完全であるとしたり、明快な回答を出せないような質問はお断りだったりするわけです。

```
概念図:
基本となる哲学 (このサイトは何であるか / what)
  `--- 派生ルール (どう運用するか / how)
  `--- 派生ルール (どう運用するか / how)
  `--- 派生ルール (どう運用するか / how)
  `--- ...
```

今回日本語版を立ち上げるにあたって、英語版と日本語版は違うコミュニティーなので、英語版の運用ルールをそのまま持ってくることはしたくない、とjmacさんが[以前書いていました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/32/30)。

それをふまえて、

**質問1** (SE社向け):
運用ルールは別物として考えるというのは同意できるのですが、実際にはどのレベルまで考え直せばいいのでしょうか。

例えば、「質問者が納得のいく回答をその場で得られればそれでいい」というQ&A哲学もありえるわけです。その場合、リンクだけの回答も、「ご意見お願いします」という人気投票的な質問もOKになります。

「これは譲れない」というようなSEネットワークとしての哲学はありますか?

**質問2:**
スコープ (歓迎する質問の範囲) は引き継いだ方がよいでしょうか?
具体的には、以下のヘルプページに書かれている内容は引き継いだ方がよいでしょうか?  
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

叩き台として:

- 対象分野に関しては「プログラミング関係」という広い範囲から始める

  - serverfault.comなどにあたる日本語SEサイトもまだ無いので
- 質問の質・アングルに関するスコープ (ヘルプページにあるリストの 1 から 5) は引き継ぐ (メタにfaq記事として蓄積しつつ)

  - SEプラットフォームの試行錯誤の成果を引き継いだ方が楽なので

というのはどうでしょうか。

**質問3:**
その他の運用ルールについては、SEネットワークで一般的に受け入れられているものも、日本語版のメタに参照できるようなQ&Aがなければメタに質問として投稿してコミュニティの意見を問い、さらにfaqとして使えるようにするのがよいかなと思います。どうでしょうか。

(例えば「リンクのみの回答はよい回答か」「コメントに回答を書くのはどうなのか」のようなもの。)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 運用ルールは別物として考えるというのは同意できるのですが、実際にはどのレベルまで考え直せばいいのでしょうか。

Stack Overflowを作ったきっかけはウェブでプログラミング質問の回答を探すのが不便だったことです。通常の掲示板やニュースグループで同じ質問を繰り返して聞いているし、未回答の質問が多かったため、質問を探しても回答にならなかったこともありました。

Stack Overflowはその問題を解決するため、プログラミングに関しての質問と回答のみのウェブサイトを作りました。当社の目的は**プログラマーへより探しやすい、適切な回答を与えることで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する**。

2008〜2009年のStack Overflow質問を読むと、現在ルール違反になる質問が多かったです。例えば「[一番好きなプログラミングジョークはなんですか？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)」（英語のみ）。今はその質問は絶対Stack Overflow英語版で許さないが、許さない理由はコミュニティが不適切と判断したから。

Stack Overflowの管理はコミュニティが行うため、このコミュニティがルールを決めるべきです。当社はその討議に参加するし、他のサイトの運用から学んだことも横通ししますが、**Stack Overflowはみんな様の物です**。まだ成長している時に「一番好きなプログラミングジョークはなんですか？」を聞きたかったらいいです。それでコミュニティが強くなったら大歓迎です。あとで大きくなってそのような質問は不適切と判断したら、ルールを変えてもいいです。最初からそのような質問は嫌だったら、最初から禁止されてもいいです。

考え直さない方がいい部分として個人が思うのは：

1. プログラミング（幅広いスコープ）について
2. 質問や回答中心なサイト

それ以外はコミュニティに任せた方がいいと思っています。

> スコープ (歓迎する質問の範囲) は引き継いだ方がよいでしょうか?
>   具体的には、以下のヘルプページに書かれている内容は引き継いだ方がよいでしょうか?

そのページは変えたほうがいいです（モデレータを選択してから自分で更新できます）。

Stack Overflowが始まった時、ルールが[相当短かった](http://web.archive.org/web/20081225024656/https://stackoverflow.com/faq)でした。そのため、ヘルプセンターのメインページに[和訳版をよくある質問として入れました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)。詳細ヘルプは初心者に不親切なため、多めのルールはそれだけを読めばいいと思っています（技術面の理由で他のヘルプセンターの記事が残っています。できれば、その1ページだけにしたいです）。

ソフト・OS・ハードウェアについて質問したい場合ここでいいと思います。サーバー管理・設置等の質問もここでいいです。将来にそのトピックが大きくなったら、別のサイト（Super UserやServer Faultの日本語版）を検討してもいいです。とりあえず、このサイトでプログラミング関連（ソフト、OS、サーバーも含む）の質問を幅広く受けた方がよいと思います。

> その他の運用ルールについては、SEネットワークで一般的に受け入れられているものも、日本語版のメタに参照できるようなQ&Aがなければメタに質問として投稿してコミュニティの意見を問い、さらにfaqとして使えるようにするのがよいかなと思います。どうでしょうか。

その通りです。ここ（メタ）で質問の投稿で当コミュニティのルールが討議できます。必要に応じて結果をヘルプに追加したり、メタでのFAQ（よくある質問集）を作ってもいいです。[英語版も同じです](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)。

---

リンクのみ回答や「おすすめを教えてください」の質問に関して：

ほとんどのツールは英語で開発しているため、日本語での情報が少ないし、検索しても判断するのが難しいケースが多い気がします。日本人プログラマーがよく戦う問題であれば、質問として残すべきと思いますが、「おすすめはなんですか？」より、具体的な問題の定義が必要とおもいます。

例えば、「おすすめなCSSフレームワークはなんですか？」より、「この問題を解決するCSSフレームワークを探しています」というような質問がいいと思います。問題の具体的な定義で、おすすめを聞いているより、問題の解答を探しています。

[Markdown に含まれるコードをシンタックスハイライトするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/165/) も [EmacsをJava用IDEとして使い倒せるパッケージはありますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73/) も具体的な要求があるために問題はないと個人的に思っています。

リンクだけの解答はあまり良くないと思っています。リンク先の説明をしないと将来にURLが変わったり、サイトが停止した場合にその解答は無意味になります。とりあえず、リンクだけの解答を探せば、サマリーぐらいを編集させたらいいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問をもうちょっと具体的にしました。みていただけますか。

Comment: @ento 後日回答を編集します！補足ありがとう

Comment: @ento 更新しました。日本語の分かりづらいところがあると教えてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。初心にかえって一から作りたい、ということですね。プラットフォームが進化しているので、SO開始当初とまったく同じではないですけど。