# タグWikiの編集について

Tags: 討議, タグwiki

タグWikiを幾つか、英語版SOから翻訳して書いてみたのですが、抜粋は翻訳できても、本文は分量が多く翻訳するのは大変だなと感じました。

例えば[iosタグ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios/info)などは、約400ワードありました。
それで、質問なのですが、タグWikiの編集時には

- 抜粋を編集するだけでいいのか
- 可能な限り本文も翻訳したほうがいいのか
- そもそも本文は日本語コミュニティ独自なもののほうがいいのか

について教えて下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 抜粋を編集するだけでいいのか

タグWikiの一番重要な部分は抜粋です。質問するときに抜粋が見えるため、抜粋を先に作成する方がいいと思います。一番大事なのは「iOSとは何か？」というより、「iOSタグはいつ・どう使うべきですか？」を示した抜粋が理想的です。

> 可能な限り本文も翻訳したほうがいいのか
>
> そもそも本文は日本語コミュニティ独自なもののほうがいいのか

SO英語版でもタグWikiの使い道が多いです。[scala](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala)（[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info)）に登録済み質問をまとめています。他のタグとの連携や重なりを示す[java](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)（[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)）もあります。そしてWikipediaからコピペしたタグも多いです。

当コミュニティが使い道を独自に探してもいいですし、英語版から翻訳も可能です。両方を各タグに適用しても問題ないです。

Answer (score 1):

英語版から翻訳する時に気をつけることとして、「このタグに関連したこういう質問はオフトピック」というような文言があったら、それについてはスキップした方がよいと思います。

日本語版でオントピックな質問の範囲は、今のところ[英語版よりも広いです](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/30)。英語版はサイトの規模が大きくなるにつれ、ソフトウェアの使い方やサーバ管理に限定したQ&Aサイトなどなどに暖簾分けしてきており、質問の棲み分けがおこなわれています。

日本語版はまだそこまでいっていないので、英語版でのオフトピックの定義をそのまま持ってくると、知らず知らずのうちに潜在ユーザーを置いていってしまうかもしれません。

具体例: [英語版の `osx`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/osx/info)  
<sub>(日本語版の [os-x](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-x) のタグwikiを見ていて気になったのでこちらにも投稿することにしました)</sub>