# ヘルプセンターの「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」の内容はこれでよいですか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)についての投稿が編集されてから5年以上が経過しました。その間に英語版の [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) でいくつか変更がありました。

変更点：
上部) [改善待ちがなくなりました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3187/14055) (put on hold -> closed)
中部) 不要な文章が削除されました
下部) 他の Stack Exchange サイトの例が増えました (Webmasters, Ask Different, Unix & Linux, Cross Validated)

現在、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは上部のみ表示されていますが、本投稿においては表示されていない部分も含めて全体的にアップデートできればと思います。

---

### 現在、表示すべき内容

スタック・オーバーフローは、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、コードを書く人のためのQ&Aサイトです。[スタック・オーバーフローでよく書けていると評価される質問](/help/how-to-ask)は、何かしらの**ソースコード**を含んでいることが多いですが、そうでなくても質問内容がおおまかにいって

- プログラミング上の具体的な問題、または
- アルゴリズムに関する問題、または
- プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり
- ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である

… ならば、この場で質問するのにふさわしいです！

まずは、[すでに質問されて](/help/duplicates)いないかどうか[確認してみて](/search)ください。[自分の質問に対して自分で回答する](/help/self-answer)のも OK です。ヘルプセンター内に、[よい質問をするためのヒント](/help/how-to-ask)をまとめたページがあります。範囲が広すぎる、質問内容が不明確、情報が足りない、または感想を求めているような質問は、[コミュニティによってクローズされる](/help/closed-questions)ことがあります。

[ここでは避けてほしい質問のタイプ](/help/dont-ask)についてもご一読ください。

---

2014年12月 entoさんのご修正 ↓

日本語版でオフトピックな内容と、ヘルプセンターの「[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](/help/on-topic)」ページの内容がずれているため、[以前の議論に従って](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/30)ヘルプの方を修正しました。主な変更内容:

- オフトピックとしている項目を削除

  - かわりに「[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](/help/dont-ask)」へのリンクを追加
- SEネットワークの他のサイトや Area 51 に誘導している箇所を削除
- 質問する前の注意点 → よい質問の仕方 → よくない質問についての注意 という順番に修正

つっこみ・改善案などあればお願いします。

修正にあたって、[Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)と[ポルトガル語版](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)を[参考](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/http%3A%2F%2Fpt.stackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fon-topic)にしました。

---

### 削ってある内容

**上のリストにある話題に沿っていても、オフトピックな質問とされることがあります。**

1. *デバッグを求める質問 (「どうしてこのコードは動かないのですか？」)* は、してほしい動作、解決したい問題やエラー、そして問題を再現するための最小限のソースコードを質問の中に書かなければいけません。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)もご覧ください。
2. *第三者が再現できない問題や、簡単な打ち間違いが原因のエラーに関する質問*は好ましくありません。このような質問をしてしまわないためにも、質問中に[問題を再現する必要最小限のプログラム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)が含まれているか、投稿前に確認してください。
3. *宿題に関する質問*では、その課題を解決するためにあなたが今までどのようなことを試したのかを要約し、そして、課題に取り組む中でどのような壁にぶつかったのかを説明してください。
4. *オススメの書籍やツール、ライブラリ、チュートリアルなどを教えて欲しい・探して欲しいといった質問*は、スタック・オーバーフローではオフトピックです。このような質問には主観的な回答やスパム投稿がよく付きます。このような質問をする代わりに、今あなたが直面している問題を説明し、それを解決するために今まで何をしてきたのかを説明してください。
5. *ツール、ライブラリ、またはお気に入りのサイト外の情報*の推奨または検索を要請する質問は、意見の偏った回答やスパムを招きがちなので、スタック・オーバーフローのトピックから外れています。かわりに、[問題を説明](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/)し、解決するために今までに何をしたかを説明します。
6. *一般的なコンピューティング ハードウェアおよびソフトウェア*に関する質問は、主にプログラミングに使用されるツールに直接関係するものでない限り、スタック・オーバーフローのトピックから外れています。
7. _専門的なサーバー、ネットワーキング、または関係するインフラストラクチャの管理_に関する質問は、プログラミングまたはプログラミング ツールに直接関係するものでない限り、スタック・オーバーフローのトピックから外れています。

**質問が具体的にスタック・オーバーフローのトピックに沿っていない場合**、[他の Stack Exchange サイト](http://stackexchange.com/sites)ではトピックに沿っている場合があります。質問に興味を持ちそうな人が…

- コンピューターに熱心な人やパワー ユーザーである場合は、[Super User](http://superuser.com) で質問します。
- プロのシステム管理者およびネットワーク管理者の場合は、[Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) で質問します。
- SEO、ドメイン名、ウェブ/メールのホスティングに関する質問を含む独自のウェブサイトの運営や管理については、[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) で質問します
- Appleのハードウェア、ソフトウェア、サービス、および関連製品については、[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) で質問します。
- Linux、FreeBSD、およびその他のUn*xのようなOSについては、[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) で質問します。
- TeX、LaTeX、ConTeXt、および関係する組版システムの場合は、[TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) で質問します。
- データベース管理者およびプロの場合は、[Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) で質問します。
- 統計学者、データアナリスト、データマイナーは、[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) で質問します。
- SharePoint に熱心な人の場合は、[SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) で質問します。

あなたの質問を受け付けるサイトが現在存在しない場合は、[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) [にコミットする](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)か新しいサイトを[提案](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)します。この場所は新しい Stack Exchange コミュニティが民主的に作成される場所です。

Answer (score 1):

現在表示されている箇所の変更（改善待ち -> クローズ）が反映されました。

[image: put on hold -> closed]