# プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？

Tags: 討議

プログラムに関する質問/そうでない　か？  教えていだだけますか。

> [Macbook Pro Retina (Yosemite)でパーティションを追加できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2849/macbook-pro-retina-yosemite%E3%81%A7%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
>
> [新しいMacを買った時に移行すべき最小のデータは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1530/%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84mac%E3%82%92%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E6%9C%80%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AF)

これらの質問は[プログラムに関する質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)なのか。そうでないか？難しいのですが、

Answer (score 13):

[別のメタ質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1551/30) へのコメントから、「幅広く受け入れる」ことの意味について補足が必要だと感じたので、こちらに回答します。

まず、こちらに挙げられている2件の質問は、

> プログラミングに関する質問か？そうでないか？

でいえば、プログラミングは直接関係し**ない**質問であると思います。

ただし、Stack Overflow 日本語版ではプログラミングが**間接的に**関わってくる分野の質問も「幅広く」受け入れています (flied onionさんの回答を参照)。その意味で、挙げられている2件の質問の分野はStack Overflowのスコープの範囲内です。

ここで「幅広く受け入れたい」というのは、「質の低い質問も受け入れたい」ということではありません。「質問の質」と「質問の分野」は別々の評価軸です:

```
^ 質問のクオリティ (明確さ、詳しさなど)
|
|
|
|                  ^
|                  ^ 質の低い質問は改善するかクローズする
|                  ^
|
|                 <- 幅広く受け入れたい ->
+-----------------------------------------------------> 関連分野
 アルゴリズム ~ プログラミング ~ OSの設定 ~ ハードウェア
```

この2つの評価軸を合わせたものが、Stack Overflowで受け入れたい質問のガイドラインです:

「分野があまりに外れた、質の高い質問」はここではオフトピックになります。例えば、「涙を流さずにタマネギをみじん切りにするには?」は料理関係のサイトであれば受け入れられるだろう、よい質問です。

「分野が適合しているが、質の低い質問」もそのままではクローズされるでしょう。

質問の質について書かれているヘルプとしては、[「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)の「トピックに沿っているか確認する」から後の内容になります。

また、投票ボタンのツールチップ (マウスカーソルを乗せると表示されるもの) にも簡単な「質」の判断基準があります:

- プラス投票: この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられる・実用的で分かりやすく書かれている
- マイナス投票: この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい

---

コメントでいただいた質問への回答:

> 大半は英語まで含めて検索すれば答えが出てくるようになっているのにそれでも質が高い質問だと判断できる材料は何ですか。

Stack Overflowでの「質」は、Stack Overflowの目的、[「プログラミングの質問に対して、適切な回答を探しやすい形で提供することで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/30)に貢献するかどうか、つまりプログラマーの仕事や趣味の役に立つかどうか、だと思っています。ここでいうプログラマーは、日本語版Stack Overflowのターゲットユーザーである、「日本語を話すプログラマー」です。

回答可能な質問は、言ってしまえば「調べれば分かる」問題です (回答を知っている人がいるのですから、その人が調べたように調べれば、分かる)。なので「調べれば分かる」かどうかで判断しようとすると、「回答不能な質問がよい質問」ということになります。回答不能な質問ばかり並んだサイトは役に立ちません。そう考えると、「調べれば分かる」かどうかは質の判断基準としては有用ではないと思います。

「質」についての判断はある程度主観的でもあり、色々な意味を含みうるやっかいな言葉でもあるので、具体的な質問を題材にしながら、今後メタで議論を深めて日本語版SOでの判断基準を醸成していくのがよいと思います。

Comment: 大半は英語まで含めて検索すれば答えが出てくるようになっているのにそれでも質が高い質問だと判断できる材料は何ですか。  
漠然とした質問でも用語すら知らない入門者にとって質の高いとなるように思いますがその点はどう思いますか。

Comment: 私は多少漠然としているのならWikiを有効に活用して二度とこのような質問が出ないように万全を期すべきではないかと思うのですが

Comment: @natsukitinyak 「検索すれば答えが出てくる質問」について: 回答の一番下に補足を入れました。ご一読いただけますか。「漠然とした質問」について: たぶん、どう漠然としているかに依存すると思います。具体例があれば、別の質問としてメタに投稿していただけると議論がしやすいと思います。

Answer (score 8):

少なくともパーティション問題に関しては、OSもソフトウェアとみなせば

> プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり

に該当すると考えてもよいと思います。

---

あとは今のところ日本版のStackExchangeがないので…という話はすでにでていて、ひとまずいいという意見も上がっています。

下記はあくまで抜粋なのでできるだけ全部読んで欲しいですが

関連META投稿抜粋：

[**ヘルプセンターの「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」の内容はこれでよいですか？**](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/728)

entoさんの質問

> 6. 一般的なコンピューティング ハードウェアおよびソフトウェアに関する質問は、主にプログラミングに使用されるツールに直接関係するものでない限り、Stack Overflow のトピックから外れています。

本家では趣旨に合わないなら合う場所をStacExchangeで探してね、合うStackExchangeが無ければ開設を提案してねというのもありますが、現状日本語版ではそれは難しそうですね。

[**英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?**](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/728)

jmacさんの回答

> ソフト・OS・ハードウェアについて質問したい場合ここでいいと思います。サーバー管理・設置等の質問もここでいいです。将来にそのトピックが大きくなったら、別のサイト（Super UserやServer Faultの日本語版）を検討してもいいです。とりあえず、このサイトでプログラミング関連（ソフト、OS、サーバーも含む）の質問を幅広く受けた方がよいと思います。

jmacさんの、とりあえず幅広く受けた方が良いという意見に私は賛同しています。はじめから捨てるよりも、途中でやっぱり違うと思えば討議して決める。（もちろん限度はあるでしょう。WindowsのExplorerでCドライブを開く方法はちょっと困りますものね。）

ここではコミュニティ（つまり利用者）の判断とそれによる改善も重要な要素ですから将来基準は変わり続けるものですが、さしあたり現時点では問題視する程ではない様に思います。

Comment: 幅広く受け入れたいということはわかりました。