# 参加の仕方は一様ではない： もっと大勢のユーザに書き込んでもらうには

Tags: 討議

[1％の法則](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%25%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87)インターネット上のコミュニティーには参加者よりもROMのほうがはるかに多いという。その問題を解決しもっと大勢のユーザに書き込んでもらうには

> [簡単に書き込みできるようにする。障害を低くすればするほど、それを飛び越えられる人の数は増える](http://www.usability.gr.jp/alertbox/20061009_participation_inequality.html)

せっかく勇気を振り絞って質問してくれている人がいるのに、質問を拒むように思われる行為は良くないと思います。ましてや、勇気を振り絞って質問してれた質問に回答がつかないことだってあるのですからそういった質問ほど賞賛する必要があるのでは？  [プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B)  の質問で質問を幅広く受け入れたいということはわかりました。その回答は７名のプラス票を得ています。

となれば、そのことを示すためにも一時的にマイナス票を禁じてはいかがですか？

幅広く受け入れるならば可能なはずです。事実サイト側は受け入れるようです。質問は５分に一度の間隔という早い間隔で投稿可能です。

質問の質は(ガイドラインにそっていないという意味で)一時的に低下するでしょうが、一つのアカウントに安定した利用者が増え2000点以上の人が増えるほど質問の質が向上するのではないでしょうか。

モデレーターの方も[通報されたものについてのみ訪問する](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%92%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87)方向ではいかがですか？
通報され「役に立つ」と判断した以上　目に見える注意警告/クローズ/削除　の三段階での対応が可能かと思いますが？いかがですか。

Yahoo!知恵袋のプログラミングには一日平均50件ほどの質問があります。(12月30～1月1日の三日間で)
回答者は各言語で最大でも5人ほどが常駐し回答を行っているようです。

一応こちらも確認してみました
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1501/revisions

https://teratail.com/（パッと見の見てくれだけは良い）←約10件  
http://w3q.jp/（横幅狭すぎ）←日付順にソートできなかったので件数は不明

質問者回答者含め潜在的に65人の１％の人物がいることになります。もっと１％と9%の人物を増やしてゆけば質の良い質問、質の良い回答が増えるのではないかと考えています。

Answer (score 16):

多数のユーザを呼び込みたい（想定されているのは特に質問者でしょうか？）という趣旨に反対するものではありませんが、提案されているような「マイナス票の一時禁止」といった他者の行動に踏み込む暫定ルール設定には賛同できません。

個人的に、**信用度(reputation)システム** と **反対投票(downvote)** はStack Overflowというサイトの大きな特色だと考えています。2015/1/3現在、スタックオーバーフローで反対投票をするには[信用度125](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)を必要とするため、本サイトで一定の活動評価を得たユーザのみが行使できる権利といえます。各ユーザに与えられた権利を歪めてまで、とにかく数を増やすという方針を採る必然性は無いと考えます。

スタックオーバーフローはまだ公開ベータ版のサービスです。無理な拡大を図るより、良質な質問と回答に賛成投票(upvote)を集めるという正攻法で、今後のコミュニティ発展に繋がってほしいと願います。

Answer (score 9):

「質問を幅広く受け入れる」と「質の低い質問を受け入れる」はイコールではありません。
「無闇にマイナス票を入れないようにしましょう」という提案であれば分かりますが、禁止というのは流石にやりすぎだと思います。
質の低い質問に対して、相当の評価をすることは質問者のためにもなりますし、多用しなければ問題ないと考えます。

Comment: 「ガイドラインにそっていない」イコール「質の低い質問」という考えでした

Comment: そういう考え方もあると思います。ただ、私は具体的な情報が少なく、回答困難な質問が質が低いと考えているので、質問を幅広く受け入れるために、マイナス票を禁止するという事に反対しました。

Comment: 私は回答困難なものほど良い質問だと思っています。なぜなら、それは検索しても回答を得ることができず、書籍にも記載されていないような質問だと捉えるためです。しかし、それが圧縮不能なほどに情報が多いために回答困難な場合、いわゆるガイドラインの書籍が一冊必要な物は質が低いと考えられます。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 「回答困難なものほど良い質問」という考え方もありだと思います。ただそういった質問には現状でもマイナス票が付いていないと思います。また、「この質問は良い質問なのにマイナス票が付いている」という物があれば、個別にメタで議論するというやり方で問題ないと思いますので、マイナス票を禁止する必要は無いと考えます。