# タグWikiでの他のStackExchangeサイトへの誘導の記載

Tags: 討議, サポート, タグwiki

タグWikiの編集レビューにこんなのがありました

> Drupalは高度にカスタマイズ可能なオープンソースのコンテンツ管理システム（CMS）で、Webアプリケーションフレームワークです。
>
> *重要*このタグを使用するのではなく、http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ (英語)に直接質問を投稿することを検討してください。

stackoverflow.com(英語)であればこのような誘導も妥当かと思いますが、ja.stackoverflow.comとdrupal.stackexchange.com(を始め大半のStack Exchangeサイト)は対象とする言語が違うと言う点で両立するものですので、一方的に誘導するのには違和感があります。

一方で、日本語話者のコミュニティが小さくここで質問しても回答が得られる可能性が小さいのであれば、より大きな英語コミュニティに誘導するのは質問者に親切かもしれません。

Stack Exchangeネットワークのなかで、ネットワーク内の他サイトに誘導する(または誘導すべきでない)ポリシーというのはあるのでしょうか。

無いのだとしたら、このような編集にはどう対応しましょうか。

Answer (score 2):

ja.stackoverflow.com において明らかにオフトピックな話題へのタグである場合を除いて、このような記述は適切に **書き換えられるべき** だと思います。たとえば質問に挙げられている例だと「drupal.SE に直接投稿せよ」という記述は消すべきで、書くにしても「英語で良いなら drupal.SE に投稿する手もあります」くらいにすべきだと思います。英語版 Stack Overflow のタグ wiki をそのまま訳すとこのような記述が紛れ込むことがありますが、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの現状に合わせるべきだ、という意味です。

---

日本語で運営されている Stack Exchange サイトは現状 ja.stackoverflow.com しかないため、英語版 Stack Overflow では他サイトに案内されるような話題でも、ある程度までは日本語版スタック・オーバーフローで扱ってよいと思います。

この話題に関して私は、[jmacさんの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/19110)や[entoさんの投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1556/19110)に賛成します。特に後者の投稿にある「日本語版スタック・オーバーフローで受け入れたい質問」の図が分かりやすいため、引用します。

> ```
> ^ 質問のクオリティ (明確さ、詳しさなど)
> |
> |
> |
> |                  ^
> |                  ^ 質の低い質問は改善するかクローズする
> |                  ^
> |
> |                 <- 幅広く受け入れたい ->
> +-----------------------------------------------------> 関連分野
>  アルゴリズム ~ プログラミング ~ OSの設定 ~ ハードウェア
> ```

このような意味で、日本版スタック・オーバーフローで扱えそうな話題へのタグの解説において、他サイトへの誘導を推奨するような文章は不要でしょう。

---

「ネットワーク内の他サイトに誘導 する/しない というポリシー」に関して、英語で運営されている Stack Exchange サイト間では、質問の migration 機能が活用されていたりと、より適切なサイトに案内する雰囲気があるように感じられます。他サイトに案内するクローズ理由が用意されている場合もあります（ただし案内先サイトで close されそうな質問を migrate するな、という議論があります。[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186802/341401)、[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/5989200)）。

この「案内」には2種類あると思います。1つは、元サイトではオフトピックであるため、オントピックでありそうなStack Exchange サイトへ案内すること。もう1つは、元サイトでもオントピックな質問だが、その話題に関してより専門的な Stack Exchange サイトがあるため、そちらに案内することです。

日本語版のサイトにおいては現状、後者の「案内」は存在できません。前者の「案内」が技術要素に関して使われるところを私は見たことがありませんが、場合によっては（英語版の）専門サイトに案内することもできると思います。尚、前者の「案内」は質問が英語で書かれていたときによく発生しています。