# 「qmailとドメインの関係について」は何故オフトピック？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

qmail というメール配送ソフトについてのこちらの質問が、オフトピックとして改善待ちの状態になりました。

> #### [qメールとドメインの関係について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/36063/1)
>
> abcdefg@user.xxx.comがあったとして、qメールを使用していて、このメールアドレスにメールを飛ばした場合になぜか、/home/userというフォルダに移動する感じでした。
>
> なぜ@userがuserに移動するのかがわかりません。
>   もうそれは既にqメールの暗黙の了解なんでしょうか？

メールサーバーを運用するなどといった意味で、[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)の「プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題」になり、この質問はオントピックなのではないかと私は思ったのですが、この質問はどのあたりがオフトピックなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

「オフトピック」か「質問内容がはっきりしない」かで悩みましたが、他の方もオフトピックとされていたため合わせました。

「qmail」ではなく「qメール」と表現していて、質問者さんはソフトウェア名を正しく認識できていませんでした。またソフトウェアの動作に関する質問と捉えることもできそうな内容でしたが、具体的な設定内容には言及されていませんでした。このことは「知りたいこと・答えてほしいことを尋ねる」ではなく「単に言いたいことを言う」と捉えました。
この２点から、質問者さんは（プログラマー等の視点ではなく）メールシステムの利用者視点の質問と判断しました。システムの利用者視点の質問であればシステム管理者に問い合わせるべきと考え、「オフトピック」を支持しました。

加えて質問文はくだけた口語調で書かれており、人にものを尋ねる態度とは言えない印象を受けました。実際、速攻でdownvoteを受けていました。
私としては、くだけた口語調をオフトピックの理由に含めるかは悩みましたが、オフトピックの投票を後押ししたのは否定しません。

Comment: 「質問内容がはっきりしない」という意図なら、確かにその通りだったと思います（現在はいくらか編集がなされているようです）。

Answer (score 2):

オフトピックに票を入れました。

少し安易に票を入れてしまった気がしますが、sayuriさんの回答と同様に「質問内容がはっきりしない」ことと、ソフトウェアの利用者視点の質問に見えました。
なので、ここで質問するよりもどうしてその設定になっているのかを管理者に聞くべき内容かと感じました。

他の方と合わせてオフトピックの理由をつけてしまいました。
「質問内容がはっきりしない」で投票するべきでしたので今後注意いたします。

今は質問が編集され設定内容についても言及されており、オントピックに見えますので再オープンに票を入れました。

Answer (score 0):

私は「オフトピック」に票を入れました。

「プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェア」の原文は "software **tools** commonly used by programmers" であり、インフラ寄りのソフトウェアである qmail は対象に含まれていないと考えたからです。

Comment: インフラ寄りだとオフトピック気味なのでしょうか？　私はjmacさんの[この投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/19110)やentoさんの[この投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1556/19110)を見て、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは[Super Userっぽいこと](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)もある程度オントピックにする方針なのかと思っていました。