# 「どのような多面体かを知るコード」はオフトピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

先日「どのような多面体かを知るコード」という質問が投稿されました。

- [どのような多面体かを知るコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48345/19110)

こちらの質問がオフトピックとして[クローズされた](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)のですが、なぜオフトピックなのか私にはよくわかりませんでした。「質問の意味が不明」や「範囲が広すぎる」ならまだ分かるのですが、主にアルゴリズムの話をしているこちらの質問がなぜオフトピックとしてクローズされたのでしょうか？

- 関連

  - [英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/19110)
  - [プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1546/19110)

Answer (score 3):

この質問は、`Graph drawing`で扱える問題です。以下に、Pythonの`NetworkX`を使った回答を書いておきます。完全ではありませんがサンプルコードとしては十分だと思います。これはプログラミングの問題なのでオントピックです。オントピックと思う人は、再オープン票を入れてください。また、英語版 Wikipedia の [Graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing)には、`Graph drawing`のソフトウェアがたくさん紹介されているので、それらのソフトウェアを使った回答が出てくることを期待しています。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

s = '''
14 0 12 
13 14 12 
13 6 14 
12 4 13 
12 0 15 
16 12 15 
16 4 12 
15 9 16 
15 0 17 
18 15 17 
18 9 15 
17 3 18 
17 0 19 
20 17 19
20 3 17 
19 11 20 
19 0 14 
21 19 14 
21 11 19 
14 6 21 
23 1 22 
13 23 22 
13 4 23 
22 6 13 
22 1 24 
25 22 24 
25 6 22 
24 8 25 
24 1 26 
27 24 26 
27 8 24 
26 2 27 
26 1 28 
29 26 28 
29 2 26 
28 10 29 
28 1 23 
30 28 23 
30 10 28 
23 4 30
27 2 31 
32 27 31 
32 8 27 
31 7 32 
31 2 33 
34 31 33 
34 7 31 
33 5 34 
33 2 29 
35 33 29 
35 5 33 
29 10 35 
30 4 16 
36 30 16 
36 10 30 
16 9 36 
37 5 35 
36 37 35 
36 9 37 
35 10 36 
39 3 20 
38 39 20 
38 7 39 
20 11 38 
40 3 39 
34 40 39 
34 5 40 
39 7 34 
18 3 40 
37 18 40 
37 9 18 
40 5 37 
21 6 25 
41 21 25 
41 11 21 
25 8 41 
32 7 38 
41 32 38 
41 8 32 
38 11 41
'''
data = np.fromstring(s, sep=" ").reshape(-1, 3)

G = nx.Graph()

# ノードの追加
nodes = np.unique(data)
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# エッジの追加
for d in data:
    G.add_edges_from([(d[0], d[1]), (d[1], d[2]), (d[2], d[0])])

# レイアウトの取得
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# 可視化
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
plt.axis()
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問中には「多面体がどのような形をしているか」と記載されているだけなので、それを「Graph drawingの問題です」と断定する根拠がよくわかりません。例えば多重投稿の他サイトでは「面が20あるから二十面体」的な回答もついていますが、現在の投稿の記述ではその回答が的外れなものなのかどうかもわかりません。「Graph drawing」についてそれなりの知識をお持ちの人にはそう見えたのかもしれませんが、さて、元の質問はそうとだけ読めるものでしょうか? 質問の意図を明らかにしてほしいと言うコメントがついているのに、それに応える暇を与えずクローズしてしまうと言うのはどうかと思うのですが、質問者の意図が明らかにならないまま放置されて「自分はこのことを聞いているのだと思う」と言う種々雑多な回答が付くのも望ましくないと思います。まずは質問者に意図を明確にしてもらうステップは必要であったと思います。

Comment: 経過は別にして、再オープンして議論すればいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: それも一つの手だろうと思います。はっきり「改善待ち」と表示されているのですから、質問者さんが改善されるのを待つのも一つの手でしょう。私はクローズにも投票しませんでしたし、再オープンにも投票するつもりはありませんが、微妙なところについては現在のルールに従ってコミュニティの判断に任せれば良いと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

「PythonでもCでもMatlabでも言語は問いません。」
と
「私が実現したいこと達成するためのコードをご存じの方がいらっしゃったら教えてください。」
という言葉から、私は**プログラムの作成依頼**と認識し、オフトピックの票を入れました。

アルゴリズムの質問であればもちろんオントピックだと思います。が、そうは読めませんでした。

Comment: でも、アルゴリズムタグがついてますよね？

Comment: あれ、すいません、プログラムの作成依頼になっている系の質問ってオフトピックなのでしょうか？　そういう系の質問に回答がつきにくいことはそうだと思うのですが、プログラミング上の具体的な問題ではあるので、オントピックの条件は満たしていると思っていました。

Comment: @Myaku さん、現在はそうですが、クローズ時点では python,c++,c,matlabのタグだけの何でもござれの状態でした。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/48345/3

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、作成依頼になっている系の質問をオフトピックにしたのは間違いかもしれません。今回の質問に限って言えはデータ形式の説明なし・言語が不問ということで「質問内容がはっきりしない」が正しかったかなと。

Comment: @htb 履歴については私も確認しておりました。ですが、その時点でもアルゴリズムがついており、どの言語でもいいから考え方を知りたいんだなぁと私は考えました。

Comment: @htb さん、はい、データ形式がよく分からないので「質問内容がはっきりしない」という理由なら私も分かります :)

Comment: @Myaku さん、すみません、「クローズ時点」ではなく「私のクローズ投票時点」が正しかったです。

Answer (score 0):

この質問ですが、クローズ票を入れる前に確認を取ればよかったと思います。
まず、SO初心者ということで言い回しやルールには詳しくないことが想定されます。
その上で、`アルゴリズム`タグがついているのだから、
コードを代理で作成してくださいといった丸投げ質問ではなく、
アルゴリズムが分からないので作り方がわからない、サンプルコードか何か無いか？
……的な質問だと解釈しました。

サンプルコードを求めることがオフトピであるなら、
その部分を削除してアルゴリズム、考え方のみの質問にしてもらえば良いと思います。