# "OSが作れない言語はありますか" がオフトピックの理由

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[OSが作れない言語はありますか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/18244/754) がオフトピックなのはなぜでしょう？

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic で列挙されている項目には、確かに含まれてはいません。ですが、同ページ上にある、コードを書くのが好きなプログラマーにとっての、興味・関心から外れる質問だとは感じませんでした。列挙されている項目は、このコミュニティのあり方を何が何でも規定するようなものなのでしょうか。

close の理由が、「質問の範囲が広すぎる」ならば、理解できました。(本が１冊かけるかもしれない)ただ、「オフトピック」で close されるのが大半であったのが、ちょっと意外だったので、質問しています。

---

追記(@11/7)

質問の時点では、割と感覚的に質問をしたのですが、自分なりに背景を整理したので、それを共有します。

現状、日本語版スタックオーバーフローが扱うべきトピックについての議論は、基本的に

[英語版SOやStack Exchange全般ではオフトピックな質問や、よしとされない回答を日本語版SOで見たらどうすればいいですか?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/754)

で初めて議論されたと理解しています。そこでの結論は、

- プログラミングに関するトピックを扱う
- それ以外はコミュニティで決める

のがいいのではないか、ということだと理解しています。それを受けて、

[ヘルプセンターの「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」の内容はこれでよいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/754)

の投稿で、 on-topic のヘルプページが、既存の StackExchange のものを参考にしながら試作版的に作成されたのだと理解しています。

---

質問の意図は、

- on-topic のヘルプページの記載は絶対ではないのではないか
- だとすると、具体的に、プログラミングに関する面白いトピックであるが、現在の on-topic の説明的にはアウトであるような問題が出てきたので、改めて、これがどうしてオフトピックなのか、コミュニティとしての答えは何になるのか、それが知りたい

です。

特に、今回具体例として上がっている質問には、質の高い(と、私は思った)回答が投稿されていました。たとえば、タイミングの問題で、今回の回答が投稿される前に close されてしまってたら、それはもったいないな、と感じたので、質問をするに至りました。

自分は、他の StackExchange についてのポリシー(が作成されるに至った経緯)をあまり知りませんので、たとえばこのようなトピックを許してしまうことが、 SE 的なアンチパターンである可能性もあると考えています。そうである場合には、どうしてそうなのか、共有いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suzukisさんは

> jmacさんのポストの趣旨ではこのような質問がオフトピックであるとは言えないと思います。

とも述べられているのですが、私はどちらかというと、jmacさんのポストにある **プログラマーへより探しやすい、適切な回答を与えることで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する。** の点をやや重視します。良い質問の存在を埋もれさせてしまう、それと反対のベクトルのもの（ノイズ）はある程度抑止する努力も、必要な時には必要だと思います（余談ですが（メタですし大目に見てください ;-) ）、私はプラス票でしか決定されない現代の政治の選挙システムはこの点で“セキュリティ面”で多大なる欠陥を抱えたアルゴリズムだと思っています）。S/N比的に、良い質問と回答のセットが、見つかりやすい、という「質の高さ」も一つの価値の高さだと思うからです。

もちろん、ここのところはあくまでもバランスの問題で、そのバランスは、コミュニティの投票によって相対的に決定・運営されていくものだと思います。たとえば、今回の質問が不適切どころかむしろ歓迎すべきだと思って、クローズに反対票を投じる人の方が多ければ、クローズを退けることも有り得たわけです。

jmacさんのポストの全体的な趣旨としては、本家のStackOverflowの現行のコミュニティルールに引きずられる必要は特になく、日本のスタックオーバーフローユーザーのコミュニティの総意で決めていって欲しいという風に受けとりました。

それで、今回の件に関しては、 **プログラマーへより探しやすい、適切な回答を与えることで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する。** という点に照らして、holywiseさんと全く同じ気持で、

> 解決策を求めるというよりは、

ネタ振りのような色合いを強く感じ、「ちょっとスタックオーバーフローらしさには、不適切かな」と思って、クローズ票を投じた次第です。

現状では、まだコミュニティが小さいので、ネットワークなどの話題もまとめて扱うという点で、カテゴリ的にはプログラミングそのものよりも広くSE的な領域まで取っていいと思いますが、[Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) 的な方まで含めてしまうと、 **適切な回答を与えることで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する** と競合してきてしまうように感じます。

Yuki Inoueさん

> 質の高い(と、私は思った)回答が投稿されていました。

また、質の高い内容を含む回答がいくらついたからといって、質問と回答の対（セット）で、同様の問題に直面した他のユーザーが、それで問題の解決の役に立つのかということが重要だと思うので、それは質問の評価自体とは関わりのないことではないでしょうか。

ネタ振りみたいな真似をあまり許容してしまうと、ネタ振りと（回答者の側は）講釈が好きな人が高い評価を集める結果にもなります。あまり実際的・実務的なプログラマーではなく、本とかネットで読み散らかした知識を右から左に交換するような人が跋扈するような雰囲気になるのは、ちょっと勘弁して欲しいなと。本家でも、古い言語（のタグ）ほど、古いユーザーがいて、そういう教科書的な講釈にうるさくて、質問者の実際的な問題（悩み）は見ないで、ただ教条的な回答をして、それを外れた回答者がいると速攻でマイナス票入れる、みたいな傾向があって、多少辟易するところがあります。本家が元々のそういった所から改善して行って、現状のようなルールになってきているのも、結局は、 **プログラマーへより探しやすい、適切な回答を与えることで、プログラマーの仕事を改善する。** を探ってきた結果ではあると思うので、方向性的には、外して欲しくないテーマだと思います。こちらでは本家みたいに流量が激しくないので、もっと初心者に「優しく」はしやすいとは思います。できるだけ、質問の情報内容が具体的になるように、導くという方向で。

Comment: 「そもそもどうして、議題の質問がオフトピックであらねばならなかったのか (オフトピックでないとすると何が起こってしまうのか)」が知りたかったと思っていたことで、それが一番説明されていると思ったので、 accept します。

Answer (score 10):

投票をした方それぞれがそのように感じたから、としか言いようがないと思いますが
オフトピックだと投票した一人として個人の見解を書いておきます。

私の場合は単純に [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) にある

> - プログラミング上の具体的な問題、または --- (A)
> - アルゴリズムに関する問題、または --- (B)
> - プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり --- (C)
> - ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である --- (D)

に該当しない質問であると考えたからです。
条件式として (A or B or C) and D が正にならないと思いました。

元の質問が興味深くないとは思っていません。これはこれで面白い題材だとは思います。

> OSが作れない言語はありますか
>   もしあるとしたら
>   どのようなことが理由としてあげられますか？

しかしこの質問は、解決策を求めるというよりは、興味本位による、多数人からの見解を募るものだと感じられました。OSを作れない言語を特定したいのではなく、なぜ他の人がそのように考えるのかを聞きたい、というのが主眼のように思われます。

したがって、スタックオーバーフローで扱うべき主題かどうかと言われるとクエスチョンです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、追記しました。

Answer (score 5):

(2015/11/06現在では)関連質問にも出ていますが、[jmacさんのポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311/5793)の趣旨ではこのような質問がオフトピックであるとは言えないと思います。

ヘルプセンターの記述についても、良い質問の方針を示すもので、それから外れる質問(このような抽象的な質問)は積極的に除外すべきという趣旨では無いと思います。

Comment: 背景を自分なりに整理して、質問を編集しました。

Answer (score 1):

11/07付の追記を受けて。

> - on-topic のヘルプページの記載は絶対ではないのではないか
> - だとすると、具体的に、プログラミングに関する面白いトピックであるが、現在の on-topic の説明的にはアウトであるような問題が出てきたので、改めて、これがどうしてオフトピックなのか、コミュニティとしての答えは何になるのか、それが知りたい

私がオフトピックとして投票したのはあくまで、**現時点でのオントピック定義にそぐわないから**、であり、もし今回のような質問を許容するような定義になっていれば、オフトピックではないとしてクローズには反対票を投じていたでしょう。

その意味で`ヘルプページの記載は絶対ではないのではないか`というのはそのとおりで、今回の質問はオントピックとして扱われるべきと考えられるのであれば、当該ヘルプページのオフトピックの定義を修正する提案を改めて起こしていただくのが良いと思います。