# Wix.com 関係のタグはどれが良いでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, タグ, 話題の範囲

WYSIWYG 的にホームページを作成できるサービス Wix https://ja.wix.com/ 関係の質問につけるタグに悩みました。

先ほどタグ [wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) が作られました。このタグ名が英語版の命名と互換性があるか調べたところ、英語版において [wix.com] は [[wixcode]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wixcode) の別名ということになっており、主たるタグ名としては [wixcode] が使われています。Wix Code とは https://www.wix.com/corvid のことで、Wix の中でも特に開発者がコーディングを行うための機能を指しています。

Stack Overflow Meta での議論が見つからなかったので推測となりますが、おそらく英語版においては特にコーディングを伴うようなプログラミングに質問の範囲を絞るためにこのような形になっているのではないかと思います。日本語版では英語版より質問の範囲が広い傾向にあるため、必ずしもこの英語版のやり方にしたがう必要はありません。WYSIWYG 部分に関係する質問やサイトの設定に関する質問もオントピックなのであれば、主たるタグ名を [wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) にするのはアリです。

また、英語版ではタグ [wix] は [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) のためのタグとなっていました。日本語版にも WiX Toolset に関係する質問が既に 2 件ある（[1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63570/19110)、[2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54244/19110)）ため、[wix](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix) は WiX Toolset 用にとっておくのが良さそうです。

このような状況で、Wix 関係の質問につけるタグの名前を悩みました。[wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) で良いでしょうか。[wixcode](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wixcode) にすべきでしょうか。英語版となるべく自然に対応がとれるようにしたいので、この 2 つのどちらかから選ぶことになるかなと思っています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) を作成したとき同様の懸念を抱いていたため、参考までに回答します。

---

まず私は、スタック・オーバーフローは Stack Overflow と異なり、**直接プログラミングに関連していない話題でも受け入れる**立場をとっていると考えました。これは、以下の 2 点を根拠にしています。

1. 「[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)」において、 `Some questions are still off topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:` 以降の文章が削除されている。
2. 上記の変更に対して、スタック・オーバーフロー Meta で議論が行われ、合意が得られている<sup>[[1]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/32986), [[2]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1546/32986)</sup>。

命名をより正確でわかりやすくするために、 Stack Overflow でオフトピックとなるトピックのタグ命名には、 Stack Overflow よりも適切なサイトを参考にする必要があります。幾つかの Stack Exchange サイトのヘルプページを見てみると、 [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) と [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) が該当しそうであることがわかったため、これらのサイトの [wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) 関連の命名を参考にしました。それぞれのサイトを見ると、 [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) には [[wix]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wix) タグが、 [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) には [[wix.com]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) タグがあり、いずれかを採用することにしました。

スタック・オーバーフローはプログラミングに関する質問もオントピックであり、 WiX ([Windows Installer XML toolset](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX)) と名称が重複する wix というタグ名は好ましくないため、他のソフトウェアやツールなどと重複する可能性が低く、 wix に関するタグであることが理解しやすい [wix.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix.com) タグがより良い命名であると判断しました。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、質問文にも書かれているとおり、 [Wix Code は Wix エディタの一機能](https://support.wix.com/ja/article/wix-%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%EF%BC%9Awix-code-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%98%8E%E7%A2%BA%E3%81%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E5%90%8C%E6%84%8F%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)であり、 Wix 全体を指すタグ命名としては不適切となるため、今回の回答では考慮していません。