# SO (en) の方針は SOja にも自動的に適用されますか？

Tags: 討議

[ChatGPT による回答は Ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/) という方針が stackoverflow.com から発表となっていますが、このような方針は自動的に ja.stackoverflow.com でも有効になるのでしょうか？

Comment: MSE での関連討議: [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/403540)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

いいえ、英語版 Stack Overflow は日本語版スタック・オーバーフローとは別のサイトです。それぞれのサイトはそれぞれのコミュニティで方針を考え、運用していくことになっています。これは日本語版スタック・オーバーフローが始まった頃からそのようにしています: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/32/19110 （回答者の jmac さんは当時の SE staff の方です）。

ちなみに別の話として、[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) で決まった network-wide な方針はデフォルトだと日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでも影響を受けます。もちろんオプトアウト的な議論はできるはずではあります。

Comment: そういう方針レベルの話は、「ほら規約のココを見れば分かるでしょ？」という状態にしてください。そうでないほど洗練されていないのであれば、もっと素早く変えて固めていってください。またスタッフかどうかとか、その人の役割とかもっと明確にしてほしいですね(ようは運営体制が不明確。運営の意思を伝達する人か場所が必要)。

Comment: その指摘はこの質問のスコープからは外れていそうなので、別途メタ質問としてご投稿いただけますか。なお jmac さんは当時はダイヤモンドマークが付いてスタッフだと分かるようになっていました。今はご退職されています。

Comment: 『そういう方針レベルの話は、「ほら規約のココを見れば分かるでしょ？」という状態にしてください。』が主題ですよ。スタッフの件は外部からは社員とそれ以外を区別できているのか明確ではないので、ここにスタッフ云々書くにしても、そういう説明を明記して書けという話です(別途ヘルプなどに説明があるべきだけど、いちいち質問としてあげないと分かりませんか？)。

Comment: 繰り返しになりますが、別途メタ質問としてご投稿いただけますか。

Comment: 関連しているので別途にする気ないの分かりませんか？

Comment: はい、特に明言もなく、分かりませんでした。SO の方針と SOja の方針は共有されるかというのが本旨ですので、SOja の方針がどう提示されるべきかはこの Q&A では脇道の議論です。コメントの範疇を超えるのでメタ質問として投稿いただきたいです。

Comment: 脇道じゃないですよ。どうするか？の本筋です。明言が必要のない話ですよ。あなたが自発的にやればいいだけなので。