# ヘルプトップページの改善 :「ワンページヘルプ」を維持すべきですか？

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ

<sub>-- この質問は2015年に@jmacさんが投稿されたものですが、再度コミュニティに確認をする必要があるのではないかと思い編集いたしました。以下が質問です。</sub>

2014年12月のスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版公開時、ヘルプセンターの翻訳は未完成だったため、[初心者向けによりわかりやすいワンページヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97-%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E6%94%B9%E5%96%84)を載せました。（内容は、2008年のSO英語版公開時に使われていたものです。）

現在2020年、日本語版公開から5年以上経過し、ヘルプセンターは殆ど翻訳されています。[ヘルプセンタートップページの改善という建設的なお声](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3179/14055)もいただいております。

ワンページヘルプをこれからも維持するほうが良いと思いますか？削除すべきでしょうか？それとも、別の文章を載せるほうが良いですか？回答欄にご投稿ください。どうぞお気軽に ♪

Answer (score 2):

ワンページヘルプの文章を削除し、[英語版ヘルプ](https://stackoverflow.com/help)のような、全てのヘルプ記事の上に「[よくある質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F)」を並べるスタイルに変更するのが良いと思われる方は、こちらにプラス票をどうぞ m_ _m。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]