# ヘルプセンター: マイナス投票 に関する記述の整合性・一貫性

Tags: 討議, サポート, ヘルプ

別の記事の一部分に書いていましたが、コメントの助言で独立させます。

マイナス投票に関するヘルプ内の記述ですが、一番の基になるであろう記事では割と強めに、「マイナス投票は極端な場合のみに限定して普通はプラス投票など他の手段で代替してください」と書いていますが、その記事は見易い場所に無くて、他に見易い位置にあるマイナス投票に言及している記事は特にプラス/マイナスに差を付けている感じは無くて、逆にコメントと併用しつつも積極的にマイナス投票を勧めるような内容もあったりします。

投票システムそのものはStackOverflowを含むStackExchange全体で共通のもので「マイナス投票する」の記述に基づいて作られているはずです。StackExchange全体の運営も、それをベースに行われているはずなので、上記のような整合性・一貫性に疑問のある記述は修正した方が良いと思われます。

ただ、個々のコミュニティは独自にルール・ガイドラインを変えて良い、かつコミュニティ内でコンセンサスが成立している、というのならそれはそれで良いのでしょうが、その場合でもヘルプの整合性・一貫性は保っておく方が良いでしょう。

ということで、以下2点を提起します。

- 「マイナス投票 に関するヘルプ記述の整合性・一貫性」を保つよう修正した方がよい。
- 整合性・一貫性の方向は議論の対象でしょうか。

---

以下関連内容。

**一番の基になるであろう記事**
[マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> **どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?**
>
> **マイナス投票に代わるものは?**

それぞれのタイトルの直後の文に考え方が記述されています。

**見易い位置にあるその他の記事**
[投票が重要なのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
最初の箇条書きの例示と最後の賛成票/反対票投票の意味説明　←**特にプラス/マイナスに差は付けていない内容**

上記に対応する英語版記事も同様に差は付けていない
[Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

> Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how …
>
> - ...good content rises to the top
> - ...incorrect content falls to the bottom
>
> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

以下の部分は日本語版だけに存在し、英語版には記述はありません。
[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)
「ごまかさない」の記述　←**マイナス投票は忌避せず却って勧める？内容**

「「信用度」とは何ですか？」の記述　←[信用度とは何ですか？どうしたら上がりますか？また失うのはどんな時ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)の要約

Answer (score 1):

整合性・一貫性についてはコミュニティのリスポンスを待つことになりますが、以下については情報をシェアさせてください m_ _m。プラス、マイナス投票に直接関係しているわけではありませんが、クリアにすべきかと思いました。

「ごまかさない」と「「信用度」とは何ですか？」の記述が現在日本語版ヘルプのトップページだけに存在するようにみえる理由は、もともと[2008年9月の英語版FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/https://stackoverflow.com/faq)で使用されていた文章を[2014年の日本語版公開時に和訳編集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8/14055)し、今もなお表示しているからです。

**「ごまかさない」の記述**

> ごまかさない
> このサイトの第一のモットーは、正直であれ、です。正しくない情報を見つけたら、マイナス投票してください。そしてコメント欄でどこが間違っているかを具体的に説明してあげてください！ 他の人の投稿を編集することもできます － サイトのコンテンツを編集を通して改善していきましょう！

> Be honest.
> Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Insert comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Even better — edit and improve the information! Provide stronger, faster, superior answers of your own!

*現時点では、[「気持ちよく参加するために」の「誠意を持ちましょう」の箇所](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)に組み込まれているようにみえます。*

**「「信用度」とは何ですか？」の記述**

> What is reputation?
> Reputation is completely optional; normal use of Stack Overflow — asking and answering questions — does not require any reputation whatsoever. As we've said all along — Stack Overflow is run by you! If you want to help us run Stack Overflow, you'll need reputation first. Reputation is a (very) rough measurement of how much the Stack Overflow community trusts you. Reputation is never given, it is earned by convincing other Stack Overflow users that you know what you're talking about.

> 「信用度」とは何ですか？
> まず、質問と回答を投稿するだけであれば「信用度」は一切気にする必要はありません。スタック・オーバーフローはユーザーのみなさんが運営するコミュニティです。運営に関わる機能にアクセスするために「信用度」というポイントが必要になります。このポイントはコミュニティからどの程度あなたが信用されているかを示すおおまかな数値です。「信用度」は、おいそれと手に入るものではありません。あなたが投稿したコンテンツを他のユーザーから評価してもらうことを通して獲得できる仕組みになっています。